# Undefined index/row errors

Tags: php, indexing, undefined

Well after learning how to fix most of my undefined index errors, at the end of the day I had a couples strange errors I could not fix with isset (or at least not when I tried).

The first one is this type of error
Notice: Undefined index: page in C:\wamp\www\forums\includes\topic.php on line 4
And on line 4:

```
 $page = ($_GET['page'] || $_GET['page'] < 0) ? "1" : $_GET['page'];
```

I tried adding an isset at the beginning and was very confused on where to add the ) at. I added it all over and every time it was still an error, so I'm now thinking maybe I am not suppose to use isset at all? No clue.

And now for the last one 
Notice: Undefined variable: row in C:\wamp\www\forums\index.php on line 65
And on line 65:

```
 $sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `forum_cats` WHERE `admin` < ".$row['admin']."+1";
```

I feel like after I know how to fix these errors I will be able to fix most undefined index erorrs. If anyone can lead me into the right direction i'd be much obliged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for isset of `$_GET['page']` and if not found or < 1 declare it as 1

```
 $page = (!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] < 0) ? "1" : $_GET['page'];
```

About your second error,there must be an error in the variable your are calling in the scope `admin`. Check your query which is selecting this column

Comment: Well the second error is weird, the forum still works with the second error, but i really just don't want to see the error.

Comment: My bad, i'll check you off as the correct answer. Basically, the second code still works, but still gives me an error. not too sure about that.

Answer (score 1):

Undefined index means that the array element you're trying to access doesn't exist. For example with your $_GET['page'] error it will be really easy to spot, because if you get an undefined index 'page' in your $_GET array you can instantly look at the URL and see if page is missing. Same deal with $row, obviously there is no element with key 'admin' in your $row array. Most of the cases you are doing something wrong if you get undefined index errors because you should know your array keys. Good luck!

Comment: no, the error is that `$row` does not exist, not that the key 'admin' isn't set in it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$page = (!isset($_GET['page']) || $_GET['page'] < 0) ? "1" : $_GET['page'];
```

In the second example, you should find where this row is comes from, or you should replace it with some default value:

```
$adminRow = isset($row['admin']) ? $row['admin'] : $defaultValue;
$sql1 = "SELECT * FROM `forum_cats` WHERE `admin` < ".$adminRow."+1";
```